# Excel - Show summarised counts of average, min and max value from range of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, average

I have 2 sets of data, set 1 is a list of accounts and a count of items for each account from set 2. Set 2 data is a breakdown of the values for each account.

The examples below are representative of the data I'm working with, and there are 1000's of records so I'm after a formulaic way of doing this.

**Set 1**

```
Account Count
123     3
128     2
135     4
157     5
...
```

**Set 2**

```
Account Value
123     11
123     31
123     98
128     77
128     99
...
```

What I'd like to do, is show a set of data containing the average of the values for each account and the min and max value.

For example:

**Output**

```
Account Count Average Min Max
123     3     47      11  98
128     2     88      77  99
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the first set and merely use **Set 2** as a basis for a pivot table.

[image]

Then drag the column `Value` four times into the `Value` box and summarize by `Count`, `Average`, `Min`, and `Max`.

[image]